# Modifying the shortcuts in Microsoft Word Equation Editor?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2010, equation-editor

Microsoft Word 2010 enables equation editing through the Equation Editor.

It is possible to use shortcuts similar to [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) code in order to enter equations in a more fluent manner than clicking on the toolbar for each symbol. One of these shortcuts, for ⟺, is `\longleftrightarrow` but this symbol is in very frequent use for me and I want to use `\iff` instead of the current very long "short"-cut. I was unable to find a standard way of modifying this shortcut or adding a new one. How can I go around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AutoCorrect to create additional shortcuts, specifically **Math AutoCorrect**.

In my Word:

```
 File -> Options -> Proofing -> AutoCorrect Options (near the top) -> Math AutoCorrect
```

Find the symbol you want (the list is alphabetical, so look for \Longleftrightarrow), then type in your desired shortcut (\iff), and hit the "Add" button.

I just did this and it worked.

Software: Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010; version 14.0.6129.5000

Comment: Too bad I saw this only now and I don't realize how I missed that option. I hope this will be of help in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use AutoHotkey. You can replace any string of entered characters with any other string of characters (in any application). Simply place the first string (called a Hotstring) between two double-colons and follow that by the second string:

For example:

::_iff::\Longleftrightarrow

::_qe::x=(-b+-\sqrt(b^2-4ac))/2a

::_em::MyEmailAddress@gmail.com

1) Go to https://autohotkey.com/

2) Download the app (it's free)

3) Install the app

4) Right-click in Windows Explorer > New > AutoHotkey script

5) Name the new file

6) Right-click the file > Edit

7) Paste the above three lines into the script*

8) Save your changes

9) Double-click the file to run it (a small green icon will appear in your tray)

Now anywhere you enter one of the hotstrings (followed by a space), it will be replaced by whatever is to the right. And in Word's Equation Editor, doing so — for the first two hotstrings — will produce a long left-right arrow and the quadratic equation, respectively.

I included the third line to demonstrate that, with this method, you can create shortcuts to quickly enter your email address or anything else (full paragraphs, etc). (Note: you can use any characters you want to create a hotstring.)

*For some reason the script does not work with a backslash in the hotstring but any other character (eg an underscore), or no character, does the trick.